# how to get the where clause in string format using CakePHP3 ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP3, there is a ORM that helps with building queries.

From the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#the-query-object), I can see that

```
$query = $articles->find(); // build a query that has not run yet
$query->where(['id' => 1]); // Return the same query object
```

So in this case, I want the string

```
WHERE `articles`.`id` = 1
```

After much googling, I found out that there is a way [to return just the where clause of a query object](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0/src/Database/Query.php#L1468).

```
$query->where(['id' => 1])->clause('where'); // Return the where clause in the form of a QueryExpression
```

More googling leads me to find out how to [get the QueryExpression to spit out string representation](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0/src/Database/Expression/QueryExpression.php#L405)

```
$query->where(['id' => 1])->clause('where')->sql($valueBinder); // Return the where clause in string format
```

Here is my problem. I don't know what the $valueBinder is supposed to look like. I don't know how to initialize it.

**I am also happy not to use ValueBinder as long as I can get the where clause in string format using CakePHP 3 ORM and in the right SQL dialect. Please assume I am using MySQL.**

Please advise.

**EDIT**

I tried to  use `$query->valueBinder()` as the `$valueBinder`.

It is empty and does not contain the associated `c:0` to the value `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you can get the SQL for any clause this way:

```
$binder = new \Cake\ORM\ValueBinder();
$query->clause('where')->sql($binder);
```

That will return the SQL with the correct placeholders, not with the values to be used. The values live in the `$binder` variable and are used for statement objects.

As I can see, you only wanted to preserve the internal structure of the `where` clause to pass it to another query in a different request. Your solution is fine, but I'd like to add that you can also encode a full conditions tree from an existing query:

```
$where = serialize($query->clause('where'));
$anotherQuery->where(unserialize($where)); // A query in another request
```

In any case, you need to be careful with what you are unserializing as taking it directly from user input will certainly lead to security problems.

Comment: Thank you Lorenzo. This is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to omit this param if you like. Please see http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_sql

In addition, you can use the Query member function traverse($visitor, $parts) to isolate the where clause. $visitor is a function that takes a value and a clause. You define the behavior of $visitor. $parts is an array of clause names. I suggest passing array('where') into this param.

Comment: your answer did not help. It returns the entire SQL query in string + the placeholder is still there. In other words, I'll get the string `SELECT Articles.* from Articles where Articles.id = c:0`

Comment: Well you asked about ValueBinder in the end. The only members of ValueBinder except for its public functions are protected. If you just want to extract the where clause, maybe there is a better route then

Comment: Okay, i have rephrased my question. Ultimately i just want to get the where clause in the right SQL dialect  in string format. Just the where clause and not the whole query. Also with the values filled in.

Comment: Thank you. I found a workaround for my situation that is less complex than I initially thought I needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is that I store the conditions in json string format.

Using the same example, what I do is

```
$data['conditions'] = json_encode(['Articles.id' => 1]); // encode into JSON string
$this->DynamicRules->patchEntity($dynamicRule, $data); // use in edit action of DynamicRulesController
```

then when I need to reuse the conditions, I do:

```
$articlesTable = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$query = $articlesTable->find(); // new query for Articles

$rule = json_decode($dynamicRule->conditions, true); // get back the conditions in associative array format
$query->where($rule); // re-assign the conditions back
```

This got me what I ultimately wanted.